# Do any sources confirm this quote from Pope Urban II's speech at the Council of Clermont?

Tags: middle-ages, christianity, crusades, pope

according to  chronicle of  Robert the Monk, Pope Urban II said -

> ... this land which you inhabit, shut in on all sides by the seas and
>   surrounded by the mountain peaks, is too narrow for your large
>   population; nor does it abound in wealth; and it furnishes scarcely
>   food enough for its cultivators. **Hence it is that you murder one
>   another, that you wage war, and that frequently you perish by mutual
>   wounds. Let therefore hatred depart from among you, let your quarrels
>   end, let wars cease, and let all dissensions and controversies
>   slumber. Enter upon the road to the Holy Sepulchre; wrest that land
>   from the wicked race, and subject it to yourselves**... God has
>   conferred upon you above all nations great glory in arms. Accordingly
>   undertake this journey for the remission of your sins, with the
>   assurance of the imperishable glory of the Kingdom of Heaven.

There are actually  five versions of the speech differ widely from one another in regard to particulars. What I would like  to know is that, is there any other source that confirms anything similar to the below part-

> **Hence it is that you murder one
>   another, that you wage war, and that frequently you perish by mutual
>   wounds. Let therefore hatred depart from among you, let your quarrels
>   end, let wars cease, and let all dissensions and controversies
>   slumber. Enter upon the road to the Holy Sepulchre; wrest that land
>   from the wicked race, and subject it to yourselves**

Answer (score 4):

This is [attributed to](https://sourcebooks.fordham.edu/source/urban2a.html) another of those present at the Council of Clermont, [Fulcher of  Chartres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulcher_of_Chartres):

> "Let those who
>   have formerly been accustomed to contend wickedly in private warfare
>   against the faithful fight against the infidel, and bring to a
>   victorious end the war which ought already to have been begun. Let
>   those who have hitherto been robbers now become soldiers. Let those
>   who have formerly contended against their brothers and relatives now
>   fight against the barbarians as they ought. Let those who have
>   formerly been mercenaries at low wages now gain eternal rewards. Let
>   those who have been exhausting themselves to the detriment both of
>   body and soul now strive for a twofold reward"

This seems pretty close in meaning to the [Robert the Monk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_the_Monk) entry cited in the question.

---

The [Gesta Francorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesta_Francorum),or Deeds of the Franks, [translations](http://sourcebooks.fordham.edu/halsall/source/gesta-cde.asp#urban) seem be be more general in term, along the line of 'fight and save your soul':

> saying: "Whoever wishes to save his soul should not hesitate humbly to
>   take up the way of the Lord, and if he lacks sufficient money, divine
>   mercy will give him enough." Then the apostolic lord continued,
>   "Brethren, we ought to endure much suffering for the name of Christ -
>   misery, poverty, nakedness, persecution, want, illness, hunger,
>   thirst, and other (ills) of this kind, just as the Lord saith to His
>   disciples: 'Ye must suffer much in My name,' and 'Be not ashamed to
>   confess Me before the faces of men; verily I will give you mouth and
>   wisdom,' and finally, 'Great is your reward in Heaven."

- Source: August. C. Krey, The First Crusade: The Accounts of
  Eyewitnesses and Participants, (Princeton: 1921), 28-30.